# I have to set width of header to more than body to fully cover. Why?

Tags: html, css

My header width is at precisely 106% to cover the length of the page, but my body max-width is 95%.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  max-width: 95%;
  font-family: ivyjournal, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  width: 106%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: ivyjournal, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 400%;
  font-decoration: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: lighter;
  left: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="text-logo">
      <h1>E.D.D</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          <li>
            <li class="Dropdown">More</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  </html>
```

Been messing around with it for a little while, and I haven't seemed to find anything on here helpful to what I'm experiencing. Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML looks invalid to me.

Comment: Can you please edit your HTML so it is actually valid?

Comment: is it me, or you are asking why you need to make the header bigger because you made the body smaller? is it this logical .. you decrease so you increase to rectify, no?

Comment: @connexo explain..

Answer (score 3):

When you use `%` to specify width it's referring to the width of it's container, not necessarily the entire page. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) out for reference.

Out of curiosity, have you tried `rem` (root-relative) or `vw` (viewport-relative width) instead of `%`?

Answer (score 1):

In CSS using percentage units will cause the affected element's size to be relative to the size of its parent element.

Your outer-most element: body, has max-width of 95% which means it will be 95% of the browser window's width.
Then the header element is inside the body, so its width set to 106% means that it will be 106% of 95% of the browser window width. `106% * 95% = 100.7 %` You got the desired result of 100% of the browser width in a very round-about way.

There is a better way to size elements based on the browser itself, rather than parent elements. This is by using the `vw` (view width) and `vh` (view height) units.

For Example:

```css
header {
  width: 88vw;    /* This will make the header width 88% of the browser width. */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

welcome to stackoverflow. I think you are problably making mistakes in your html structure. Make something similar to my code, use it as a structure for your further experiences. Check how the width are set to 100%.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <title>Title</title>
</head>    
<body>
 <header>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <li class="Dropdown"><a href="#">More</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div> 
  </header>
  <div class="text-logo">
    <h1>E.D.D</h1>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
            h1 {
                color: white;
                position: relative;
                font-size: 400%;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: lighter;
                left: 50px;
                top: 10px;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            body {
                background-color: #333;
                max-width: 100%;
                font-family: ivyjournal, sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            header {
                width: 100%;
                height: 40%;
                position: relative;
                font-family: ivyjournal, sans-serif;
                background-color: black;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
```

If you want to learn how to create dropdowns and stuff you can check out bootstrap and follow their documentations here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I just wanted to add that I have more html, I just wanted to provide the main idea. I don't see anything much different aside from the bootstrap

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have direct children of `html` other than `head` and `body`.

Comment: @connexo Yes, sorry, you're right. Usually I don't use header too.

Comment: `header` is a perfectly valid and semantic element. That has nothing to do with the invalidity of your suggestion - all content of a webpage must be inside the `body`.